# Android using Otto on Samsung: NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.otto.ThreadEnforcer during initialization

Tags: android, event-bus, otto

I'm using the OttoSingleton to use the EventBus in the application. 
Initialize it like this:

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    OttoSingleton.getInstance().register(this);

}
```

My `OttoSingleton`:

```
public class OttoSingleton {

private static String TAG = OttoSingleton.class.getSimpleName();

private static Bus bus;

private volatile boolean paused;

private final Vector<Object> eventQueueBuffer = new Vector<>();

private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private OttoSingleton() {

}

public static Bus getInstance() {
    if(bus == null){
        bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }
    return bus;
}

public <T> void postToSameThread(final T event) {
    bus.post(event);
}

public <T> void postToMainThread(final T event) {
    try {
        if(paused) {
            eventQueueBuffer.add(event);
        } else {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        bus.post(event);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "POST TO MAIN THREAD: BUS LEVEL");
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "POST TO MAIN THREAD: HANDLER LEVEL");
        throw e;
    }
}

public <T> void register(T subscriber) {
    bus.register(subscriber);
}

public <T> void unregister(T subscriber) {
    bus.unregister(subscriber);
}

public boolean isPaused() {
    return paused;
}

public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
    this.paused = paused;
    if(!paused) {
        Iterator<Object> eventIterator = eventQueueBuffer.iterator();
        while(eventIterator.hasNext()) {
            Object event = eventIterator.next();
            postToMainThread(event);
            eventIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

}

My gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
```

And I receive the error in the OttoSingleton initialization:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.otto.ThreadEnforcer at com.comeouts.android.library.singletons.OttoSingleton.getInstance(OttoSingleton.java:34)                                                                         at com.comeouts.android.activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:146)
```

On this row:

```
 bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
```

The problem occurs only on Samsung phones. 
What can be the solution?

Comment: Can you see [this](https://github.com/square/otto/issues/141) and [this](https://github.com/square/otto/issues/183) issues. It may helps you.

Comment: see this line `Same problem, looks to be happening only when multiDex is enabled ` above link